# named ui-view='main' is not displaying anything in angular 4.x

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am running [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) with angular 4.x. Below code is not rendering anything and I did not get any error message too. But when I changed to $default as a view name, then I am getting the page.Please suggest me.

```
<app-root>
<ui-view name='main'></ui-view>
</app-root>
```

Below is the angular State Definition,

```
export const appState = {
name: 'app',
views : { 
  main : { 
  component: AppComponent 
  }
}    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When Angular application bootstrap's, it wipes out the inner content of `app-root`(root) component. What ever you put inside `root` component will appear until Angular application bootstrap. Generally this place has been used to add `Splash screen`, `loader` to show initial loading.

To see your `ui-view` to replace via ui-router configuration, you should add `ui-view` inside `app-root` component HTML.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<ui-view name='main'></ui-view>`
})
export AppRootComponent {


}
```